# Brunch only copies file, does not compile them?

Tags: brunch

I don't understand why and this is driving me crazy.

I copied a skeletons and did my work on it, the less file was compiled correctly.

I move the project to an other folder, with some folders changes, and it stops to work.

I don't understand why.

The less file is located at `app/assets/css/general.less`

And here's my config :

```
exports.config =

  paths:
    public: 'public'

  files:
    stylesheets:
      defaultExtension: 'less'
      joinTo:
        'public/css/general.css': /^(app)/
```

The result is simple, in `public/css/`, I have a `general.less` file, not `general.css` ...

Can someone help me figuring it out?

Thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I found the solution of my question in the [doc](https://github.com/brunch/brunch/blob/master/docs/config.md) ; There is a specific configuration variable located in the conventions part : `assets`.

Here's the defintion :

> `assets` key: anymatch set. Default value: `/assets[\\/]/`. If test gives
>   true, file won't be compiled and will be just moved to public
>   directory instead.

And since the default value was "assets" ...

Comment: This was driving me nuts too - for anyone else having trouble, you can solve by adding this to your `brunch-config.js`

`conventions: {
    assets: () => false // forces brunch to compile files in /assets folder
  }`